# How to clear then refresh database in one JSON block?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

Currently I use the following JSON script to process our tabular cubes on the server (SSAS 2019)

```
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "Cube1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to clear and then process the database/cube, all in one JSON script/file.

However, when i execute below script in SSMS:

```
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "clearValues",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "Cube1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "Cube1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 11, position 1
```

I also tried including a comma between the different blocks to separate them but i get a similar error regardless.

So what is the correct way/syntax to combine these two JSON refresh blocks together in one script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, this can be achieved through sequential operation!!

```
{
  "sequence": {
    "maxParallelism": 1,
    "operations": [
      {
        "refresh": {
          "type": "clearValues",
          "objects": [
            {
              "database": "SomeCubeName"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "refresh": {
          "type": "full",
          "objects": [
            {
              "database": "SomeCubeName"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```